# Time Evolving Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Suppose I have a 2D channel with bottom boundary $y(x)=0$ and top boundary $y(x)=1+a\sin(x)$  with an initial dye distribution $D(x,y,0)=D(x)$. I have no flux boundary conditions along the walls: $
\frac{\partial D}{\partial n} = 0 $.  The dye evolution is described by: $$\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}=k\nabla^2 D$$

I am interested in the longtime form of this solution, in particular I want to know how the effective diffusivity varies from the $a=0$ case. What methods could I use to solve this analytically? As a follow-up, is there any literature that you can refer me to that discusses this (does not need to be analytic)?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @JackT Just edited, thank you!

Comment: Because of the weird geometry, there is really no hope for a "pencil and paper" solution. Finite Element Method is the way to go here.